# How to get value as int if the button title in in terms of percentage?

Tags: ios, swift

This is the application to calculate tip and split it between number of selected users.

In the screenshot below, I've 3 buttons under "Select tip" section.
I want to use the values as int for calculating the tip.
How do I get the value as int?

For eg. If I select 10% button, I want only 10 as the value for carrying out further calculations.

[image: Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 13 Pro - 2022-03-14 at 21.51.48strong text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution to work best in my case.

```
@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    tipSelected = sender.currentTitle!
    
    let tipSelectedMinusPer = tipSelected.dropLast()
    print(tipSelectedMinusPer)
}
```

dropLast() function deletes the last character from the string. So, basically we drop the % symbol in this case and are left behind with plain number as value.